# (.NET Core 1.0 && net46) MVC Errors in Views classes in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

i'm getting Errors in Views classes in Views folder (See images) in Visual Studio. 
i'm using <strike>ASP.net (5)</strike> (Now) .NET Core 1.0 MVC core 1.0..
**Project.json**

```
  {
    "userSecretsId": "OIDD",
    "root": "wwwroot",
    "commands": {
      "ef": "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Commands",
      "web": "OIDD"
    },
    "compilationOptions": {
      "emitEntryPoint": true,
      "preserveCompilationContext": true
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc2-16411",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-*",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0-*",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-*",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc2-16281",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-17119",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor": "1.0.0-rc2-17119",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0-rc2-17119",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor": "1.0.0-rc2-16282",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-16453",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-16290",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc2-16160",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-16100",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-*",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc2-16097",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-16120",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
      "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-16389",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection": "1.0.0-rc2-16137",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis": "1.0.0-rc2-16618",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-16854",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-*",
      "OpenIddict.Core": "1.0.0-*",
      "OpenIddict.EF": "1.0.0-*"
    },
    "exclude": [
      "wwwroot",
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "frameworks": {
      "net46": { }
    },
    "publishExclude": [
      "**.user",
      "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "tools": {
      "dotnet-publish-iis": "1.0.0-*",
      "dotnet-razor-tooling": "1.0.0-*"
    },
    "content": [
      "Areas",
      "Views",
      "wwwroot",
      "hosting.json",
      "config.json"
    ]
  }
```

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X6wN.png) 
|
[Project Hierarchy and Errors in Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKCVr.png)

*Edit: edited question after better understanding of the problem*

Comment: It's complaining about AspNet because packages and namespaces were renamed to AspNetCore and you are still using AspNet. I would recommend sticking to rc1-final unless you really know what you are after. With rc2 you should consider using dotnet and not dnx since dnx is going away. Tooling is not yet ready for rc2 either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Github Issue: "ASP.NET Core RC2 is not yet supported in VS - we are working on an update to VS2015 that supports the new dotnet-cli system and ASP.NET Core RC2."](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4186#issuecomment-190311832)